# Android Retrofit - "Request Entity Too Large" Error

Tags: android, node.js, http, retrofit, retrofit2

I am sending an encoded(base64) image to the node.js express server and the image has 25000 characters. But when request sent, server gives "Request entity is too large" error. I think, this error depends to the Android request because I am able to send the same request with the Postman.

Here is the Retrofit Client:

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {
    private static final String main_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(main_url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And the request:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/updateStudentInfo/")
Call<Bts> updateStudent(@Field("StudentId") String id,
                          @Field("StudentName") String name,
                          @Field("StudentSurname") String surname,
                          @Field("ParentName") String parentName,
                          @Field("ParentSurname") String parentSurname,
                          @Field("ParentEmail") String parentEmail,
                          @Field("LicencePlate") String licencePlate,
                          @Field("Address") String address,
                          @Field("ParentPhone") String phone,
                          @Field("StudentPhoto") String photo);
```

Comment: If you are using body parser, you can try increasing request limit on the server side. 

Example: app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}) );
More details: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions

Comment: @A.OnurÖzcan I am able to post the same request via Postman :/ It is not dependent to the limit. Also I've already done it.

Comment: Actually I saw your note about postman. But this response is returning from server. So, I think it must be server related.(Request mime type could be different on Postman) 
I suggest that you should increase limit right way. bodyParser.urlEncoded({type: '*/x-www-form-urlencoded', limit: '10mb'});
By the way, why don't you use @Multipart annotation?

Comment: @A.OnurÖzcan can you give a short example for @Multipart?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ you can have a look 'Form Encoded and Multipart' part. I asked that because files are usually sent with multipart type.

Comment: @A.OnurÖzcan I solved this issue. Thank you very much. Eyvallah...

Comment: What was the issue? @AhmetAzizBeşli

Comment: @free_style I was trying to send a big request to the server. I was converting the image to base64. And there was an error called “Request Entity Too Large”